# How to display my own html form instead of doing {{ form.as_p }} with forms.py django?

Tags: html, css, django, authentication, django-forms

I have forms.py file with usercreation form inside of it. It works just fine, but the only way I can display fields in it(first_name, last_name, username, email, password and password confirmation is by writing {{ form.as_p }}. I want to display it the way I could style it. Are there any ways to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the css style by using form widgets

```
class BasicForm(forms.Form):
   first_name = models.CharField(...,
                              widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'myclass'})
   last_name = models.CharField(...,
                             widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'myfieldclass'})
```

later use class css design

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own HTML at various degrees of granularity. It's described [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).

[Crispy Forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a widely used package that makes fancy form layout a lot easier. Also you can do most of the work in Python by coding a Crispy Layout object, rather than by writing a complicated HTML template.